# Passing current locale through Gatsby's Head API — <IntlProvider> needs to exist in the component ancestry

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, gatsby

I am using `gatsby-plugin-intl` and in works in multiple pages. All I have to do is:

```js
import {useIntl} from 'gatsby-plugin-intl'
```

and then I can do:

```js
const intl = useIntl()
```

so that later in the code, I can use `intl.locale` as the value of the current locale, or `intl.formatMessage` to retrieve translations. This works, as I said, in multiple pages.

But now I am trying to pass `intl.locale` through Gatsby's Head API and this is where things stop working as expected.

My index.js looks like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import Seo from "../components/utils/seo";
import {useIntl} from "gatsby-plugin-intl";

const Index = () => {
  return <Layout location="home" />;
};

export default Index;
```

For testing purposes, I hard-coded the current locale and passed it like this (after default exporting Index from the previous code example):

```js
export const Head = () => {
  return <Seo currentLocale="en" />;
};
```

This gets passed ok and I can use it in my Seo component. But if I try this:

```js
export const Head = () => {
  const intl = useIntl()
  return <Seo currentLocale={intl.locale} />;
};
```

I get the following runtime error (in the browser only, not in the dev console):

```bash
Error in function invariant in ./node_modules/@formatjs/ecma402-abstract/lib/utils.js:76

[React Intl] Could not find required `intl` object. <IntlProvider> needs to exist in the component ancestry.
```

So, why is

```js
const Index = () => {
  const intl = useIntl()
  return <Layout location="home" />;
};
```

not giving me any errors, but

```js
export const Head = () => {
  const intl = useIntl()
};
```

is — on the very same page? How should I get to the current locale from my index.js page and pass it via Head API to the Seo component correctly?

Many thanks in advance for any tips with this!